# Excel unresponsive when manipulating large amount of data from add-in

Tags: excel, office365

I find that if I edit large amounts of data in an Excel sheet using an Excel add-in in the new, web-baed add-in model, the add-in becomes really unresponsive even though the getselectedata and setselecteddata are both async functions. Is this expected or are there ways to increase performance?

Comment: Depends on how much data we are talking about and how unresponsive these add-ins geht when you say "really".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the getSelectedDataAsync (or set) functions that are available in all Office host applications, you could try to use the Excel specific (2016 only, unfortunately) APIs. These might be faster, especially when you use batching or syncing for the operations you perform on the document.

Please refer to the documentation of the 'ctx' APIs and the ctx.run() function specifically for batching. https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview?product=excel